# Missing <li> circles in div with scroll (overflow:auto;)

Tags: html, css

So I have `div id="main_content"` with scroll (`overflow:auto;`) and a list inside it. The problem is, that circles near lists items are missed! How can I fix it?

```
#main_content {
    height: 620px;
    margin-left: 390px;
    margin-top: -350px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 620px;
}

#main_content ul li {
    display: list-item;
    list-style: circle;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `display: list-item;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've used a reset stylesheet, or perhaps set `margin: 0;` in your css, you'll need to reset the `margin-left` value of the `ul` or `li` element(s), unless you prefer to use `list-style-position: inside;` (the other value being, obviously, `outside`).

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: circle;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p7Fm3/).

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
#main_content ul{list-style-position:inside}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/KVTp9/ So you must've reset your `ul` or `li` somewhere. If that doesn't work you may want to apply `list-style:circle;` to your `ul` tag instead of your `li`.